# Consider the series $\sum_{n=0}^\infty \frac{(x-3)^n}{3^n \sqrt{n+1}}$

Tags: calculus

$$\sum_{n=0}^\infty \frac{(x-3)^n}{3^n \sqrt{n+1}}$$

Its interval of convergence is of one of the forms $(a,b)$, $(a,b]$, $[a,b)$ or $[a,b]$.

1. What is $a$?
2. What is $b$?

I know the interval on convergence is $|x-3|<3$ but i am not sure how to change it into $a$ and $b$?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By ratio test we find that the radius of convergence is $R=3$ and the interval is centred at $x=3$ and for $x=0$ the series is convergent by Leibniz test and for $x=6$ the series is divergent (why?) so the interval of convergence is $[0,6)$.

Answer (score 3):

Hints:

$$a_n:=\frac{(x-3)^n}{3^n\sqrt{n+1}}\implies \left|\frac{a_{n+1}}{a_n}\right|=\left|\frac{(x-3)^{n+1}}{3^{n+1}\sqrt{n+2}}\frac{3^n\sqrt{n+1}}{(x-3)^n}\right|=\frac{|x-3|}3\sqrt\frac{n+1}{n+2}\xrightarrow [n\to\infty]{}\frac{|x-3|}3$$

Now, you want the rightmost expression to be less than $\,1\,$ , so...

Remember: for real $\,a,x\,\,,\,\,\,a>0\;$ , we have that

$$|x|<a\iff -a<x<a$$

Comment: SO If |x−3|/3 is less then 1 therefore -6< x <6 right?

Comment: Nop. It must be $\,0< x < 6\,$ , and in fact we have convergence on the left extreme point, too.

Answer (score 3):

You forgot the absolute value

$$ |x-3|<3 \implies  -3<x-3<3 \implies \dots.$$

By the way, I am answering based on your derivation.